# Python - Pandas data frame: customized aggregation function after groupy?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I am using some aggregation function after doing the groupby on a pandas dataframe, like:

```
my_df.groupby(['id']).agg(['count'])
```

I am wondering is it possible to have a customized aggregation function? For example, in my data frame:

```
id       color 
--------------------     
001       red
001       blue
001       yellow
002       green
002       black
003       yellow
003       white
003       blue
```

I want to create a customized function called `all_color`, so I could do something like:

```
my_df.groupby(['id']).agg(['all_color'])
```

and get the output data frame as:

```
id        all_color
--------------------
001       [red,blue,yellow]
002       [green,black]
003       [yellow,white,blue]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` function, and `tolist()` method to convert to values to list.

```
In [12]: df.groupby('id')['color'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
Out[12]:
id
1      [red, blue, yellow]
2           [green, black]
3    [yellow, white, blue]
Name: color, dtype: object
```

Use `reset_index` to convert the series to dataframe

```
In [21]: df.groupby('id')['color'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
Out[21]:
   id                  color
0   1    [red, blue, yellow]
1   2         [green, black]
2   3  [yellow, white, blue]
```

Comment: Thanks! Then the output doesn't seem to be a data frame, can we make it a data frame? Thanks!

Comment: Or at least assign a name to the new column, so it could be referred later ... thanks.

Comment: Updated to convert series to dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this as a dataframe you can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: pd.pivot_table(df, values="id", index=df["id"], columns=df["color"], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
Out[11]:
color  black  blue  green  red  white  yellow
id
1          0     1      0    1      0       1
2          1     0      1    0      0       0
3          0     1      0    0      1       1
```

Note: this is very similar to the output of [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html).