# [pandas]: Groupby on column(s), then define multiple (including some custom) aggregation functions simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I need to be able to define, in one groupby/agg statement, the sum & the division of two separate columns and save them as a new column, and then calculate the sum of another column.

Mods, please examine my desired output first before reviewing this question. Looking at other questions on this site, I could only figure out how to write custom aggregation functions for one aggregation column, not multiple.

For example, [Python - Pandas data frame: customized aggregation function after groupy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872890/python-pandas-data-frame-customized-aggregation-function-after-groupy) asks a similar question, but provides no advice as to how to define custom functions for multiple columns, simultaneously.

---

Below is a problem statement, my attempt at a solution, and my desired result.

Here is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['backyard', 'store', 'bank', 'backyard', 'backyard', 'bank', 'store'],
                   'is_orange': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   'is_non_orange': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   'melons':     [73, 81, 94, 174, 23, 71, 65]})
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
df.groupby(['location']).agg(
    'total orange/non-orange' : df['is_orange'] + df['is_non_orange'],
    'percent_orange'          : df['is_orange'] / (df['is_orange'] + df['is_non_orange']),
    'sum_melons'              : sum(df['melons']))
```

With the desired output being:

```
df = 

location    total_orange/non-orange    percentage_oranges    melons
backyard                        3.0                  0.66       270
bank                            2.0                  0.00       165
store                           2.0                  1.00       146
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer (inspired by discussions with Ry on the Python Discord server, and my own testing):

Define the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'location' : ['backyard', 'store', 'bank', 'backyard', 'backyard', 'bank', 'store'],
    'is_orange': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'is_non_orange': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    'melons': [73, 81, 94, 174, 23, 71, 65]
})
```

We then define a function that will be performed over each of the subgroups defined by the eventual `.groupby()` statement.

```
def stats(df_subgroup):
    return pd.Series({
    'total_oranges' : (df_subgroup['is_non_orange'] + df_subgroup['is_orange']).sum(),
    'percentage_oranges' : (df_subgroup['is_orange'] / (df_subgroup['is_non_orange'] + df_subgroup['is_orange'])).mean(),
    'melons': (df_subgroup['melons']).sum()
})
```

The output is given by this command:

```
df.groupby(['location']).apply(stats)
```

With the output being:

```
    total_oranges   percentage_oranges  melons
location            
backyard    3.0 0.666667    270.0
bank    2.0 0.000000    165.0
store   2.0 1.000000    146.0
```

I have also tested this with multiple `.groupby()` columns, and it seems to work fine. One thing of note is the use of the `.mean()` function. I am sure there is a better way to extract the calculated value for each subgroup, but this is a decent workaround for now.

---

Lastly, I would like to mention that **this approach requires additional tweaking if the column entries are not both float/int**. For example, defining the `is_orange` and `is_non_orange` columns as Booleans:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'location' : ['backyard', 'store', 'bank', 'backyard', 'backyard', 'bank', 'store'],
    'is_orange': [True, True, False, False, True, False, True],
    'is_non_orange': [False, False, True, True, False, True, False],
    'melons': [73, 81, 94, 174, 23, 71, 65]
})
```

And attempting to run the same logic as before:

```
def stats(df_subgroup):
    return pd.Series({
    'total_oranges' : (df_subgroup['is_non_orange'] + df_subgroup['is_orange']).sum(),
    'percentage_oranges' : (df_subgroup['is_orange'] / (df_subgroup['is_non_orange'] + df_subgroup['is_orange'])).mean(),
    'melons': (df_subgroup['melons']).sum()
})
    
df.groupby(['location']).apply(stats)
```

Yields the following error: `NotImplementedError: operator 'truediv' not implemented for bool dtypes`.

Instead, we modify the logic to be:

```
def stats(df_subgroup):
    return pd.Series({
    'total_oranges' : (df_subgroup['is_non_orange'].sum() + df_subgroup['is_orange'].sum()).sum(),
    'percentage_oranges' : (df_subgroup['is_orange'].sum() / (df_subgroup['is_non_orange'].sum() + df_subgroup['is_orange'].sum())).mean(),
    'melons': (df_subgroup['melons']).sum()
})
    
df.groupby(['location']).apply(stats)
```

(Note the use of `.sum()` at the end of each Boolean column call)

This yields the desired output:

```
    total_oranges   percentage_oranges  melons
location            
backyard    3.0 0.666667    270.0
bank    2.0 0.000000    165.0
store   2.0 1.000000    146.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (suggested by shimmer on the Python Discord server):

Define the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['backyard', 'store', 'bank', 'backyard', 'backyard', 'bank', 'store'],
                   'is_orange': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   'is_non_orange': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   'melons':     [73, 81, 94, 174, 23, 71, 65]})
```

We can write:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df  = df.groupby('location').agg('sum')
df2['total_oranges'] = df['is_orange'] + df['is_non_orange']
df2['percentage_orange'] = df['is_orange'] / (df['is_orange'] + df['is_non_orange'])
df2['melons'] = df['melons']
```

With the output being:

```
    total_oranges   percentage_orange   melons
location            
backyard    3   0.666667    270
bank    2   0.000000    165
store   2   1.000000    146
```